# setting multiple column using one update

Tags: mysql

How to set multiple columns of a table using update query in mysql?

Answer (score 415):

Just add parameters, split by comma:

```
UPDATE tablename SET column1 = "value1", column2 = "value2" ....
```

See also: [mySQL manual on UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: Is it possible to add where clause at the end for both columns?

Comment: @71GA I don't think so. That sounds like something you'd need two different statements for.

Answer (score 86):

```
UPDATE some_table 
   SET this_column=x, that_column=y 
   WHERE something LIKE 'them'
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's take an example where you have a `people` table and you would like to update the `age` and the `name` column for the person with `id` equals to 5. The query will look like this:

```
UPDATE people SET age = 34, name = "John" WHERE id = 5
```