# Cant UPDATE date in mysqli from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have js

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#responds .del_button", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var clickedID = this.id.split("-");
        var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; 
        var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; 

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "stop_duty.php", 
            dataType:"text", 
            data:myData,
            success:function(response){
            $('#item_'+DbNumberID).fadeOut("slow");
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But cant UPDATE NOW() in mysqli
**stop_duty.php**

```
$delete_row = $mysqli->query("UPDATE combats_duty_logs SET active= '0', duty_time_stop= NOW() WHERE id=".$idToDelete);
```

error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

```
delete xhrCallbacks[ id ];
```

what's wrong? Without NOW() its working good.

Comment: `active= '0' duty_time_stop= NOW()` You're setting values to 2 columns, so you need to separate it by a comma. You really ought to check the server error logs when you get a 500 error, since it's such a generic error.

Comment: yeap, my fail but still dont working.

Comment: Like aynber said, check the server logs for the true error. Also, did you make sure duty_time_stop is truly a datetime field?

Comment: A 500 response code means there was an error on the server.  What's the error?  Check your PHP logs, turn on error reporting, debug, etc.  "Something went wrong" isn't really an error we can help with.

Comment: yes, its datetime field

Comment: As a side note you seem to be vulnerable  to SQL injection. Make sure you prepare your mysql statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: hmm "[Thu May 10 17:23:50 2018] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `www.site.ru' does NOT match server name!?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting multiple column using one update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667439/setting-multiple-column-using-one-update)

Comment: maybe something wrong with data:myData,?

Answer (score 0):

```
$delete_row = $mysqli->query("UPDATE combats_duty_logs SET active= '0' duty_time_stop= NOW() WHERE id=".$idToDelete);
```

You need to separate the values you want to set with a ',':

```
$delete_row = $mysqli->query("UPDATE combats_duty_logs SET active= '0', duty_time_stop=NOW() WHERE id=".$idToDelete);
```

This error could be found by simply checking for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma in your SQL query.
Also, remember that if you're accepting user input from a user, do not put it directly into your SQL query.

As a malicious user can put something like `1; DROP TABLE combats_duty_logs;` and now your query:

```
$delete_row = $mysqli->query("UPDATE combats_duty_logs SET active= '0' ,duty_time_stop=NOW() WHERE id=".$idToDelete);
```

Has turned into:

```
$delete_row = $mysqli->query("UPDATE combats_duty_logs SET active= '0' ,duty_time_stop=NOW() WHERE id=1; DROP TABLE combat_duty_logs;");
```

Which will update whatever you set where UID = 1, but it'll also drop the entire table.